# Spinner values get doubled every time I click on the activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-spinner

I am using a fragment activites. One of my activity has a spinner. I set its adapter. The problem is whenever I switch to that activity, spinner values increase. It actually adds the the same values into the spinner without removing the previous ones. How to solve it? my code is following:

```
public class AddPackageFragment extends Fragment {

    View rootView; 
    EditText packageName;
    EditText packageNumber;
    Spinner network;
    CheckBox sim1;
    CheckBox sim2;
    RadioGroup type; 
    RadioGroup through;
    Button addPackage;
    Button actDetails;
    ArrayList<String> networks = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    Context context;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_package, container, false);
        initializeViews();
        setNetworks();
        setSpinner();

        return rootView;
    }

    void initializeViews() {
        packageName = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.pName);
        packageNumber = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.pNumber);
        network = (Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.networkS);
        sim1 = (CheckBox)rootView.findViewById(R.id.sim1);
        sim2 = (CheckBox)rootView.findViewById(R.id.sim2);
        type = (RadioGroup)rootView.findViewById(R.id.typeGroup);
        through = (RadioGroup)rootView.findViewById(R.id.throughGroup);
        addPackage = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.addPackage);
        actDetails = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.activationDetails);
        context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        addPackage.setActivated(false);
        actDetails.setActivated(false);
    }

    void setNetworks() {
        networks.add("Mobilink");
        networks.add("Telenor");
        networks.add("Ufone");
        networks.add("Warid");
        networks.add("Zong");
        networks.add("Add New");
    }

    void setSpinner() {
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.spinner_item, networks);
        network.setAdapter(null);
        network.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Comment: Object of AddPackageFragment.java is not recreated but its onCreateView() is again called (on the same object). As pointed in the answers below, you need to clear your array so that in each call only the new values are filled in the array and older are cleared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on @Dimmerg

Based on the Fragment lifecycle, your `onCreateView` will get called more than one time. So you have to take that into consideration and clear values (or Lists) accordingly.

[image: Fragment lifecycle]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
void setNetworks() {
    networks.clear()
    networks.add("Mobilink");
    networks.add("Telenor");
    networks.add("Ufone");
    networks.add("Warid");
    networks.add("Zong");
    networks.add("Add New");
}
```

I think it's because your array not cleared, not the spinner adapter.